# http_build_query with same name parameters

Tags: php, http, url

Is there a way to build a query automatically with `http_build_query` using parameters with the same name?

If I do something like

```
array('foo' => 'x', 'foo' => 'y');
```

They are obviously overwritten within the array, but even if I do:

```
array('foo' => array('x', 'y'));
```

The function creates something like `foo[0]=x&foo[1]`, which isn't what I want, since I need the parameters in this format `foo=x&foo=y`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can solve this by doing substitution on the result of `http_build_query()` where the `[0]`, `[1]`, …, suffixes are URL-encoded.

```
$vars = array('foo' => array('x', 'y'));
$query = http_build_query($vars);
# $query is now foo%5B0%5D=x&foo%5B1%5D=y (URL-encoded foo[0]=x&foo[1]=y)
$query = preg_replace('/%5B\d+%5D(?==)/', '', $query);
# $query is now foo=x&foo=y
```

The look-ahead (`(?= … )`) ensures it only replaces values at the end of a name because they are always followed by an `=`.
PHP won't produce indices with leading zeroes, so `\d+` (1 or more digits) is sufficient to detect them.

Some systems require the square brackets without indices inside them. In that case you can use this:

```
$query = preg_replace('/%5B\K\d+(?=%5D=)/', '', $query);
# $query is now foo%5B%5D=x&foo%5B%5D=y (URL-encoded foo[]=x&foo[]=y)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function I created to build the query and preserve names. I created this to work with a third-party API that requires multiple query string parameters with the same name.

```
function custom_build_query(
    array|object $query_data,
    string $numeric_prefix = "",
    ?string $arg_separator = null,
    int $encoding_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738
): string {
    // Cast to array if object is supplied.
    $query_data = is_object($query_data) ? get_object_vars($query_data) : $query_data;
    
    // Use supplied arg_separator value, defaulting to the `arg_separator.output` php configuration.
    $arg_separator = $arg_separator ?? ini_get("arg_separator.output");
    
    // If PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 is specified, use rawurlencode to encode parameters.
    $encoding_function = $encoding_type === PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 ? "rawurlencode" : "urlencode";
    
    $query = [];
    foreach ($query_data as $name => $value) {
        $value = (array) $value;
        $name = is_int($name) ? $numeric_prefix . $name : $name;
        array_walk_recursive($value, function ($value) use (&$query, $name, $encoding_function) {
            $query[] = $encoding_function($name) . "=" . $encoding_function($value);
        });
    }
    return implode($arg_separator, $query);
}
```

Usage:

```
echo custom_build_query(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => [3, 4]]);
```

Output:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&c=4
```

Note: The function's signature is fully compatible with [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). The only difference is, of course, the function will not use brackets for sub-array parameters.