# Google Closure Compiler and multipart/form-data not working

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers, google-closure-compiler

I'm making a request to the google closure compiler API service:

```
   $content = file_get_contents('file.js');

   $url = 'http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile';
   $post = true;
   $postData = array('output_info' => 'compiled_code', 'output_format' => 'text', 'compilation_level' => 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS', 'js_code' => urlencode($content)));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'));
```

But the request is failing and I get this error message from google:

```
   Error(18): Unknown parameter in Http request: '------------------------------0f1f2f05fb97
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name'.
   Error(13): No output information to produce, yet compilation was requested.
```

I looked at the headers and this Content-Type header is being sent:

```
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8; boundary=----------------------------0f1f2f05fb97
```

Not sure if that added boundary is normal? And how do I prevent this as google doesn't seem to like it?

Thank you,
Wesley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Google's API doesn't support multipart/form-data data. Which seems a bit lame to me...

According to the [PHP documentation on curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt):

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data,
>   while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

So it should work if you change the 4th line of your code to something like this:

```
$postData = 'output_info=compiled_code&output_format=text&compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS&js_code=' . urlencode($content);
```

In other words, you have to do the URL encoding yourself - you apparently can't rely on cURL to take an array and encode it for you.

Comment: I tend to use http_build_query for url encoding an array

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [`http_build_query()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) prior to sending POST data (array) to cURL.

```
string http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] )
```

So your `$postData` should look like this:

```
$postData = http_build_query(
                                array(
                                'output_info' => 'compiled_code', 
                                'output_format' => 'text', 
                                'compilation_level' => 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS', 
                                'js_code' => urlencode($content)
                                )
                            );
```

Comment: This is clearly better than my answer. Well done sir/madam, have an upvote :-)

Comment: Update: it appears that this isn't working. Any ideas why? The solution below does work. No hint from google on what's wrong, as they just return with a correctly formed json response, but the compiled_code parameter is empty if using http_build_query, and not so when using the solution below (one long string). (note, for json i simply changed output_format to text, otherwise it resulted in a completely empty response and needed to see if google would at least process it. Perhaps google does not receive the entire request?

Comment: Here's the error I get when changing output_info to errors: optimized = {"errors":[{"type":"JSC_PARSE_ERROR","file":"Input_0","lineno":1,"charno":10,"error":"Parse error. missing ( before function parameters.","line":"function+test%28%29+%7B+alert%28%22bla%22%29%3B+%7D+test%28%29%3B"}]} - with this as input: $content = 'function test() { alert("bla"); } test();';

Comment: well that's obviously not a problem in my code, but in yours.

Comment: No, the exact same code sent via the appending method works, it's only when I use http_build_query that it doesn't. Anyway, it's working with that method so this certainly isn't a very high priority for me to find an answer to, I just found it interesting that there still appears to be a difference.. Probably google that can't even handle http_build_query ?...

Answer (score 3):

1.) Don't use an array() to avoid switch to [multipart/form-data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-notes):

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as
>   multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode
>   the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

2.) Don't use http_build_query() to avoid double encoding problems (@Wesley). In addition you aren't able to use keys twice (I know [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171667/318765), but its ugly).

Some of my error messages by using http_build_query():

> JSC_PARSE_ERROR Input_0
>   Parse error. illegal octal literal digit 9; interpreting it as a decimal digit
>   Parse error. syntax error
>   ERROR - Parse error. missing ( before function parameters

3.) My proposal:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Expect:',
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // don't set it to low! sending and response needs time
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); // automatically sets supported encodings
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // for debugging response header
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // for debugging request header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // false would echo the answer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// settings
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    'output_format=json'
    .'&output_info=compiled_code'
    .'&output_info=warnings'
    .'&output_info=errors'
    .'&output_info=statistics'
    .'&compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS'
    .'&warning_level=verbose'
    //.'&output_file_name=default.js'
    //.'&code_url='
    .'&js_code=' . urlencode($js_code)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//$response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) . $response; // for debugging request header
print_r(json_decode($response, true));
```