# cURL postfields issue

Tags: php, curl, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to work with [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref), unfortunately I stumbled upon a problem with cURL's postfields. It seems to be that when I specify an array here, it doesn't work the way it's supposed to work.

By passing an array to the postfields like this:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    "output_info"       => "compiled_code",
    "output_format"     => "text",
    "compilation_level" => "SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS",
    "js_code"           => urlencode($jsCode),
]);
$result = curl_exec($this->curl);
var_dump($result);
```

I get an error 13 from Google, indicating I haven't set the `output_info` parameter. However, when I pass the postfields as a literal string, like the following, everything does work fine and I get the minified JS code in the response.

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'output_info=compiled_code&output_format=text&compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS&js_code=' . urlencode($jsCode));
$result = curl_exec($this->curl);
var_dump($result);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume you are setting `CURLOPT_POST` and running PHP 5.4+?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes, both correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Closure Compiler and multipart/form-data not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975758/google-closure-compiler-and-multipart-form-data-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate question. See [Google Closure Compiler and multipart/form-data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975758/google-closure-compiler-and-multipart-form-data-not-working).

Long story short - if you pass an array to curl_setopt it will change Content-Type header to multipart/form-data which is not supported by google's API.

Comment: Seems like it, would explain why I wasn't able to find the issue. Pretty lame.

Comment: If this is the case, you should mark and close this question as a duplicate.